# bash -i behavior and "why is my terminal hung?"

Tags: bash, tty

This happens on every distro I've tried:

```
$ cat | bash -i
bash-3.2$ ls
foo bar
bash-3.2$
```

And now the session is hung. Ie, you get **one** command and then you pretty much have to close the terminal window. SIGTERM (aka ^C) is caught by bash but it won't get you back to a working shell.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the `-i` causing bash to fight with cat for control of the tty, but I can't find anything definitive. Can anyone explain what's going on? And how do I automate input to a program that's running `execlp("/bin/bash", "bash", "-i")` without hanging? Do I have to write an `expect`-like program that handles tty vagaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer:  yes, you're going to have to use Expect.

As for *why* it's failing:  based on its behavior, `bash -i` turns on `readline` (even with `--noediting`), which plays rather badly with pipes.  It also appears to be setting terminal modes (including non-blocking mode) via `stdout` instead of `stdin`, which means you lose the expected behavior of most control characters.  (It is not, however, reading the tty directly.)

Side note:  `^C` sends `SIGINT`, not `SIGTERM`.  Both are, however, trapped in interactive (`-i`) mode; `SIGHUP` works to kill it.